How can I edit 2sxc entity structure, like add property, change property type etc. programmatically via C# code?
I need to update entities programmatically via C# code. I have some code already that creates IApp object of the target 2sxc app. From there I've been reading data via appObject.Data["MyEntityType"].List.
But what I want to do is I want to access entity type and be able to add/delete/update properties and change data structure programmatically, not the data itself.

My understanding is that you want to add/remove/reconfigure fields, and not add data. As of now it there is no public API to do this. That means you can of course try to do it and access internal APIs, but they could change without warning.

The same need keeps coming up for us on at least 1/3rd of our projects. I am surprised the APIs are still internal and subject to change. I hope this ends up on the roadmap (if its not already).

Since it's not possible ATM, but will probably become more and more important, I suggest you create an issue describing exactly what the need is, why, and how much the API should enable you to do, so we can probably schedule it for v19

Did that: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/3457
